# Swift 3 error handling and variable accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, swift3

I have a question on how to use the new error handling in Swift.

I'm reading contents of a file into a data object:

```
var overallData: Data?

//load file contents into data object
let dataFileURL = NSURL(string: fileName)

do {
    overallData = try Data(contentsOf: dataFileURL as! URL)
} catch { 
    print("\(error)")
}
```

The problem is that I always encounter this error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The problem is that the `overallData` object is set as `nil`. But if I don't define a data variable outside the do-catch,

```
let dataFileURL = NSURL(string: fileName)

do {
    overallData = try Data(contentsOf: dataFileURL as! URL)
} catch { 
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Later on, I can't use the `overallData` object because the system keeps telling me it's a variable not defined yet. So it looks like new variables defined in the do-catch loop can only be locally accessed inside the loop.

Do you know how to solve this problem? I do need to use the `overallData` object elsewhere.

Comment: Use [`init(fileURLWithPath:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/url/1780183-init), which (a) is `URL`, not `NSURL`; and (b) is a file URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer assumes your error is with the line:

```
overallData = try Data(contentsOf: dataFileURL as! URL)
```

If you are getting the "fatal error" on another line, please update your question.

---

Your error has nothing to do with the `do/catch/try`.

Your problem is the force unwrapping of `dataFileURL` which is `nil`.

Your problem is this line:

```
let dataFileURL = NSURL(string: fileName)
```

This is returning `nil` because `fileName` isn't a valid URL.

Assuming `fileName` is a path to a local file, you need to do:

```
let dataFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName)
```

Also note the use of `URL` instead of `NSURL`. There is no sense in using `NSURL` in Swift 3.

Comment: Hello, you are absolutely right, it is the problem with the dataFileURL being nil. When this issue is solved, things work out smoothly. Thank you!